# Copy TClientDataSet contents with field configurations

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dataset

I would like to copy a whole TClientDataSet instance into another so I can recover any changes made in the original one. I've tried to saveToStream, to copy the data property but in all cases I loose the fields configurations (displayLabel, size, etc.)

Is there a way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi will only stream published properties.  You may need to tweak things a bit to get everything out & back correctly.  See http://www.delphipages.com/news/detaildocs.cfm?ID=145 for an example of the hooks.

-- MarkusQ

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

DestClientDataSet.Data := SrcClientDataSet.Data;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  [TClientdataset.Clonecursor](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=82&Itemid=27) ?